# How can I provide a callback to an forms-authenticated page when using oAuth?

Tags: asp.net, session, oauth, forms-authentication

I am accessing an API that uses oAuth and as part of retrieving the request token, I am sending through a callback URL. I am encountering an issue where the callback request just causes authentication to fail and the user is redirected to my login screen.

I can append the session id as a parameter to the callback url, and this allows me to access session, but when I try to append the .ASPXAUTH value the oAuth provider chokes returning "Could not generate a  request token". Perhaps the auth key is too long?

What is the usual approach to authenticating via oAuth and calling back to a logged-in user, using forms authentication and session state?

Comment: Have you tried using a session cookie?

Comment: Excellent - thanks Mark. Obvious answer - but I haven't used cookies too much before so it didn't occur to me. If you want to add this as an answer - I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a session cookie?